# Reopen a Qt desktop app if an instance is already running

Tags: windows, qt, mutex, show, msdn

I'll try my best to explain my problem, but I am quite new to all of this. I have a Windows desktop Qt application. There can only be one instance of the application running. This is ensured by MSDN mutex handle in `main.cpp`.

```
HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, lpName);

if (mutex == NULL || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS){
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Info", "Application is already running.");
    return 0;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is reopen the running app if someone tries to open the app. By reopen I mean `show()` the `MainWindow` which might be hidden (by `hide()` method) at this point. I don't really know how this can be achieved.

Comment: First of all - you are mixing Qt with WinAPI. Are you trying to do this in Qt-way or WinAPI-way?

Comment: see this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html

Comment: @jaskmar well not having too much experience it's difficult for me to say which way I want to do it. I don't know how to do it either way nor whether it can be achieved both ways. I imagine finding the instance of the app has to be done by WinAPI, but showing the window by Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[How I show application when open application again Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882803/how-i-show-application-when-open-application-again-qt)

`QLocalServer` and `QLocalSocket` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QSystemSemaphore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemsemaphore.html#details) which could be accessed by multiple processes (instances of your class). Also this article might be helpful: [Inter-Process Communication in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html).

Please also note that mixing `Qt` with `WinAPI` is not a good idea when it is not necessary.